# My datetime is saved in UTC even though the server is in PST zone

Tags: sql-server

I have table with one of my columns has default datetime as `getdate()`
My server is in PST zone.
But when I insert a record it is saved with UTC format. It is inserting with a time difference of 7hrs.
Can anyone please  suggest why it happens.
I am using the below query to know my server time zone.

```sql
DECLARE @TimeZone VARCHAR(50)
EXEC MASTER.dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation',
'TimeZoneKeyName',@TimeZone OUT
SELECT @TimeZone
```

Comment: It is better to use `DATETIMEOFFSET` data type instead of `DATETIME` for your scenario.

Comment: How is data inserted? You're assuming the default is used, but applications are free to explicitly supply a value. Also note that `DATETIME` has no format and no time zone information, meaning that it's up to applications to interpret the value -- whether the value is in the DB server's local time zone, the app server's local time zone, UTC or something else entirely is left up for grabs and is something all parties must agree on.